# Relation between lubs of a set and its subset

Tags: real-numbers

If $A\subset B$ and $B$ is bounded above, show that $\operatorname{lub}A \leq \operatorname{lub}B$.

This seems very obvious but I am not able to write a proper solution for this. Does it really require a proof or we can logically conclude this? Kindly help.

Comment: By "lub" you mean supremum, i.e. least-upper-bound? Are we talking of real numbers?

Comment: Yes, it requires a proof.  To show that the least upper bound of a set $S$ is less than $x$ all you need to do is to show that $s≤x$ for all $s\in S$.

Comment: Yes @OttavioBartenor , by lub I mean supremum of a set

Answer (score 0):

Yes it requires a proof, by logically concluding.

Let $x$ be the least upper bound of $B$, then it's an upper bound for $A\subseteq B$, hence $\sup A\le x$.